# Exclusion constraint on a bitstring column with bitwise AND operator

Tags: postgresql, indexing, constraints, bit-manipulation, postgresql-9.1

I read about [Exclusion Constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE) in PostgreSQL but can't seem to find a way to use bitwise operators on bitstrings.

I have two columns `(name text, value bit(8))`. And I want to create a constraint that basically says this:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT route_method_overlap
EXCLUDE USING gist(name WITH =, value WITH &)
```

But this doesn't work since:

> operator &(bit,bit) is not a member of operator family "gist_bit_ops"

I assume this is because the `bit_ops` operator `&` doesn't return `boolean`. But is there a way to do what I'm trying to do? Is there a way to coerce `operator &` to cast its return value as a boolean?

Currently using Postgres 9.1.4 with the "btree_gist" extension installed, all from the Ubuntu 12.04 repos. But the version doesn't matter. If there's fixes/updates upstream, I can install from the repos. I'm still in the design phase.

Comment: It is essential to provide your version number with advanced questions like this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You installed the extension [`btree_gist`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html). Without it, the example would already fail at `name WITH =`.

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
```

The operator classes installed by `btree_gist` cover many operators. Unfortunately, the `&` operator is not among them. Obviously, because it does not return a `boolean` which would be expected of an operator to qualify.

#### Alternative solution

I would use a combination of a b-tree **multi-column index** (for speed) and a **trigger** instead. Consider this demo, tested on PostgreSQL **9.1**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t (
  name text 
, value bit(8)
);

INSERT INTO t VALUES ('a', B'10101010'); 

CREATE INDEX t_name_value_idx ON t (name, value);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_t_name_value_inversion_prohibited()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (
      SELECT FROM t
      WHERE (name, value) = (NEW.name, ~ NEW.value)  -- example: exclude inversion
      ) THEN

       RAISE EXCEPTION 'Your text here!';
   END IF;

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;

CREATE TRIGGER insup_bef_t_name_value_inversion_prohibited
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF name, value  -- only involved columns relevant!
ON t
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION trg_t_name_value_inversion_prohibited();

INSERT INTO t VALUES ('a', ~ B'10101010');  -- fails with your error msg.
```

In Postgres 10 or older use instead:

```
...
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_t_name_value_inversion_prohibited();
```

See:

- [Trigger function does not exist, but I am pretty sure it does](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/255319/3684)

[`~` is the inversion operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-bitstring.html).

The extension `btree_gist` is *not* required in this scenario.

I restricted the [trigger to `INSERT OR UPDATE OF` relevant columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) for efficiency.

A **check constraint** wouldn't work. I quote [the manual on `CREATE TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html):

> Currently, `CHECK` expressions cannot contain subqueries nor refer to
> variables other than columns of the **current row**.

Bold emphasis mine.

Should perform very well, actually better than the exclusion constraint, because maintenance of a b-tree index is cheaper than a GiST index. And the look-up with basic `=` operators should be faster than hypothetical look-ups with the `&` operator.

This solution is not as bullet-proof as an exclusion constraint, because triggers can more easily be circumvented - in a subsequent trigger on the same event for instance, or if the trigger is disabled temporarily. Be prepared to run extra checks on the whole table if such conditions apply.

#### More complex condition

The example trigger only catches the inversion of `value`. As you clarified in your comment, you actually need a condition like this instead:

```sql
IF EXISTS (
      SELECT FROM t
      WHERE  name = NEW.name
      AND    value & NEW.value <> B'00000000'::bit(8)
      ) THEN
```

This condition is slightly more expensive, but can still use an index. The multi-column index from above would work - if you have use for it anyway. Or, more efficiently, a simple index on name:

```
CREATE INDEX t_name_idx ON t (name);
```

You commented that there can only be a maximum of 8 distinct rows per `name`, fewer in practice. So this should still be fast.

#### Ultimate INSERT performance

If `INSERT` performance is paramount, especially if many attempted INSERTs fail the condition, you could do more: create a materialized view that pre-aggregated `value` per `name`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mv_t AS 
SELECT name, bit_or(value) AS value
FROM   t
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

`name` is guaranteed to be unique here. I'd use a `PRIMARY KEY` on `name` to provide the index we're after:

```
ALTER TABLE mv_t SET (FILLFACTOR=90);

ALTER TABLE mv_t
ADD CONSTRAINT mv_t_pkey PRIMARY KEY(name);
```

Then your `INSERT` could look like this:

```sql
WITH i(n,v) AS (SELECT 'a'::text, B'10101010'::bit(8)) 
INSERT INTO t (name, value)
SELECT n, v
FROM   i
LEFT   JOIN mv_t m ON m.name = i.n
                  AND m.value & i.v <> B'00000000'::bit(8)
WHERE  m.n IS NULL;          -- alternative syntax for EXISTS (...)
```

The [`fillfactor`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) is only useful if your table gets a lot of updates.

Update rows in the materialized view in a `TRIGGER AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF name, value OR DELETE` to keep it current. Cost and gain of  additional objects have to be weighed carefully. Largely depends on your typical load.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Is the use of a trigger here for speed? As opposed to say a CHECK constraint? What I want to prevent is bit overlap. So for any 2 columns with equal `name` fields, val1 & val2 must = `B'00000000'`. That's why I figured an exclusion constraint would work here. So I don't think indexing on `~ value` would be constructive. Also, with this condition, keep in mind that there could only ever be 8 columns with matching `name` fields.

Comment: @Falmarri: I amended my answer with your clarifications, addressing check constraints, and adding more.

Comment: Very thorough answer, thanks. I think the more complicated trigger would work perfectly fine since inserts should be "relatively" rare compared to selects.