# Equivalent to exclusion constraint composed of integer and range

Tags: postgresql, operators, range, constraints, postgresql-9.3

I need to have something equivalent to this `exclusion` constraint

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t (
    i int,
    tsr tstzrange,
    exclude using gist (i with =, tsr with &&)
);
ERROR:  data type integer has no default operator class for access method "gist"
HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.
```

I guess the problem is obvious from the error message. How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install the additional module [**`btree_gist`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html) to make it work. The module installs the missing operator class.

Details in this related answer:

- [Exclusion constraint on a bitstring column with bitwise AND operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126180/exclusion-constraint-on-a-bitstring-column-with-bitwise-and-operator/11128280#11128280)

More at this answer on dba.SE:

- [PostgreSQL EXCLUDE USING error: Data type integer has no default operator class](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/37373/3684)