# PostgreSQL daterange not using index correctly

Tags: postgresql, indexing, date-range, b-tree-index, gist-index

I have a simple table which has a user_birthday field with a type of date (which can be
NULL value)

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  user_id bigserial NOT NULL,
  user_email text NOT NULL,
  user_password text,
  user_first_name text NOT NULL,
  user_middle_name text,
  user_last_name text NOT NULL,
  user_birthday date,
  CONSTRAINT pk_users PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
)
```

There's an index (btree) defined on that field, with the rule of NOT
user_birthday IS NULL.

```
CREATE INDEX ix_users_birthday
  ON users
  USING btree
  (user_birthday)
  WHERE NOT user_birthday IS NULL;
```

Trying to follow up on another idea, I've added the extension `btree_gist` and created the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_users_birthday_gist
  ON glances.users
  USING gist
  (user_birthday)
  WHERE NOT user_birthday IS NULL;
```

But it had no affect either, as from what I could read it is not used for range checking.

The PostgreSQL version is 9.3.4.0 (22) [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/)
and issue also exists in 9.3.3.0 (21) [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/)

I've been intrigued by the following queries:

Query #1:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE user_birthday <@ daterange('[1978-07-15,1983-03-01)')
```

Query #2:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE user_birthday BETWEEN '1978-07-15'::date AND '1983-03-01'::date
```

which, at first glance both should have the same execution plan, but for some
reason, here are the results:

Query #1:

```
"Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..52314.25 rows=11101 width=241) (actual
time=0.014..478.983 rows=208886 loops=1)"
"  Filter: (user_birthday <@ '[1978-07-15,1983-03-01)'::daterange)"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 901214"
"Total runtime: 489.584 ms"
```

Query #2:

```
"Bitmap Heap Scan on users  (cost=4468.01..46060.53 rows=210301 width=241)
(actual time=57.104..489.785 rows=209019 loops=1)"
"  Recheck Cond: ((user_birthday >= '1978-07-15'::date) AND (user_birthday
<= '1983-03-01'::date))"
"  Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 611375"
"  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_users_birthday  (cost=0.00..4415.44
rows=210301 width=0) (actual time=54.621..54.621 rows=209019 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: ((user_birthday >= '1978-07-15'::date) AND
(user_birthday <= '1983-03-01'::date))"
"Total runtime: 500.983 ms"
```

As you can see, the `<@ daterange` is not utilizing the existing index, while
`BETWEEN` does.

Important to note that the actual use case for this rule is in a more complex query,
which doesn't result in the Recheck Cond and Bitmap Heap scan.
In the application complex query, the difference between the two methods (with 1.2 million records) is massive:
Query #1 at 415ms 
Query #2 at 84ms.

Is this a bug with daterange?
Am I doing something wrong? or `datarange <@` is performing as designed?

There's also a discussion in the [pgsql-bugs mailing list](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20140402211018.309.99248@wrigleys.postgresql.org)

Comment: What happens to the execution plan if you run `analyze users;`, followed by query #1?

Comment: That was one of the 1st things I tried when I saw this issue. It had no affect.

Comment: What's the rationale for indexing on `NOT user_birthday IS NULL` rather than the date itself?

Comment: The question should display `CREATE INDEX` script.

Comment: I'm ignoring records which have no birthday, so I don't need to index them. The rationale is to keep the index smaller. Per @ErwinBrandstetter request, added the CREATE INDEX, although as mentioned - nothing special in it.

Comment: Agreed, it's bit unwieldy if you have range types and need to check for upper / lower bound, excluding / including, NULL, to build the statement. It *would* be nice if Postgres could do that for us.

Comment: @ShaharHadas it is a long time ago I know, but I am facing same issue today.
Have you detected the issue here ?

Comment: Nope. This project is long gone by now, but since then I kept using BETWEEN as it provided the needed functionality, just in a different syntax

Answer (score 5):

`BETWEEN` [includes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INCLUSIVITY) upper and lower border. Your condition

```
WHERE user_birthday BETWEEN '1978-07-15'::date AND '1983-03-01'::date
```

matches

```
WHERE user_birthday <@ daterange('[1978-07-15,1983-03-01]')
```

I see you mention a **btree** index. For that use simple comparison operators.

Detailed [manual page on which index is good for which operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-types.html).

The range type operators [`<@` or `@>` would work with **GiST** indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INDEXING).
Example:
[Perform this hours of operation query in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108477/native-way-of-performing-this-hours-of-operation-query-in-postgresql/22111524#22111524)

Comment: Tried that already. postgres automatically converts [] daterange to [) daterange. No affect - still Seq Scan.

Comment: GIST is used when you have an index on a daterange field. here I'm just using a daterange to filter.

Comment: @Sash: Combine `<@` with a gist index on a range type - or a functional index. For the btree index use simple comparison operators.

Comment: I don't have a range type. Added the test table creation. I'm trying to create the complex gist index as you suggested, but it seems that in order to do so, I need to create an index which takes the user birthday as the two values of the range.

Comment: Well, I'd rather suggest to use simple comparison operators with the btree index. :) A GiST index might be a good idea for a nearest neighbor search, but your example works better with simple comparison operators and a  btree index.

Comment: I've just reported this as a possible bug to postgres. I'll update this question once I hear back. As for the index, after some more googling, it seems the solution is btree_gist extension, but I'm still looking into this.

Comment: @Sash: It's not a bug, the operators are just not defined. Why wouldn't you want to use the cheaper simple operators? There is nothing to gain for you here ...

Comment: Because I already have the range to filter by in another table as daterange. so now I need to use upper and lower to extract those values with COALESCE with infinity and -infinity. so its ugly ... and I don't yet if it adds slowness or not. I'm working on those changes right now.

Comment: regarding the operators - am I missing something? according to this they do exist: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-range.html - look at the timestamp example.

Comment: The operators exist - else your query would have failed altogether. What's missing are the *index operator classes*. btree indexes cannot handle `<@` `@>` in standard Postgres. Consider the link to the manual I added last. It explains more than my first link.

Comment: moving forward on your suggestion, I've added btree_gist, and then added the following gist index, but still it doesn't uses any index

Comment: @Sash: [`btree_gist`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/btree-gist.html) allows you to include the listed basic types in a GiST index, not the other way round (implement additional operators for btree indexes). That might be a lot more complicated. I don't know of a module providing what you are after. If you should find something, be sure to post an answer here.