# Speedup of Time range Queries

Tags: postgresql, indexing, b-tree, gist-index

**Situation**:

Table Waypoints is relatively large (150M rows) and contains (amongst others) the columns user_id and a timestamp tracked_at.

Table Storyline is a smaller Table (300K rows) that contains information about time episodes (t_min to t_max, also available through the tsrange segment_time), user_id and more.

**Aim**: Add the information of the segments table to the points table where the user_id matches and timestamp is in t_range (there is one unique match).

```
EXPLAIN  CREATE TABLE t4 AS SELECT
  w.waypoint_id,
  s.storyline_id
FROM waypoints w JOIN storyline s
ON  w.tracked_at <@ s.segment_time and w.user_id = s.user_id;
```

**Question**: How can I use indexes here to speed up the join?

What I thoght would be necessary here, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824314/postgresql-daterange-not-using-index-correctly) is a [btree_gist](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/btree-gist.html) index on (user_id, t_segment_time) on storyline or, if I use a query with t_min and t_max instead of the range, a normal index on (user_id, t_min, t_max DESC).
However, I always get a query plan similar to the following:

```
"Hash Join  (cost=329264.29..8085010946.88 rows=553075874 width=16)"
"  Hash Cond: (w.user_id = s.user_id)"
"  Join Filter: (w.tracked_at <@ s.segment_time)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on waypoints w  (cost=0.00..4503125.76 rows=152813376 width=24)"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=323059.13..323059.13 rows=496413 width=38)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on storyline s  (cost=0.00..323059.13 rows=496413 width=38)"
```

I understand the sequential scan on waypoints (after all, i want all points back), but I feel as if an index scan rather than a Sequential scan on Storyline should be much faster. Is there a reason why a sequential scan should be faster here? If not, what indices are needed to achieve an index scan?

**Edit:**
As recommended by a_horse_with_no_name, here are the create statements of the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE public.storyline
(
  storyline_id bigint NOT NULL,
  user_id bigint NOT NULL,
  t_min timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  t_max timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  ...
  segment_time tsrange,  -- as tsrange(t_min, t_max, '[)')
  CONSTRAINT storyline_pkey PRIMARY KEY (storyline_id)
)

CREATE INDEX i_storyline_uid_t
  ON public.storyline
  USING btree
  (user_id, t_min, t_max);

CREATE INDEX i_storyline_uid_t_2
  ON public.storyline
  USING btree
  (user_id, t_min, t_max DESC);

CREATE INDEX i_storyline_uid_tseg
  ON public.storyline
  USING gist
  (user_id, segment_time);
```

And the waypoints:

```
CREATE TABLE public.waypoints
(
  waypoint_id bigint NOT NULL,
  user_id bigint,
  tracked_at timestamp without time zone,
  ...
CONSTRAINT "none" PRIMARY KEY (waypoint_id)
)

CREATE INDEX i_waypoints_id
  ON public.waypoints
  USING btree
  (waypoint_id);

CREATE INDEX i_waypoints_uid_t
  ON public.waypoints
  USING btree
  (user_id, tracked_at);
```

Aso to the explain analyze: I would love to do that but so far I lost patience after waiting for more than a day. I assumed that if a simple traversal of the big table lasts 2-3 minutes then adding unique counterparts from a much smaller other table should be feasible in a couple of hours at most.
But I can let it run for longer and let you know the results.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes) and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** (instead of a "simple" `explain`)

Comment: My version of Postgres is too old for ranges, but looking at the documentation, your index doesn't know about uniqueness of the matching range. Add to the creation of storyline `EXCLUDE USING GIST (user_id WITH =, segment_time WITH &&)`. Of course make sure you `ANALYZE`.