# Get spare time out of stored activities start and end times

Tags: postgresql, function, range, plpgsql, gaps-and-islands

I am trying to implement a function that calculates the spare time out of stored activities start and end times. I implemented my database on PostgreSQL 9.5.3. This is how the activity table looks like

```
activity_id | user_id   | activity_title                     | starts_at                     | ends_at 

(serial)    | (integer) | (text)                             | (timestamp without time zone) |(timestamp without time zone)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           | 1         | Go to school                       | 2016-06-12 08:00:00           | 2016-06-12 14:00:00
2           | 1         | Visit my uncle                     | 2016-06-12 16:00:00           | 2016-06-12 17:30:00
3           | 1         | Go shopping                        | 2016-06-12 18:00:00           | 2016-06-12 21:15:00
4           | 1         | Go to Library                      | 2016-06-13 10:00:00           | 2016-06-13 12:00:00
5           | 1         | Install some programs on my laptop | 2016-06-13 18:00:00           | 2016-06-13 19:00:00
```

Actual table definition of my real table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.activity (
  activity_id serial,
  user_id integer NOT NULL,
  activity_title text,
  starts_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  start_tz text NOT NULL,
  ends_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  end_tz text NOT NULL,
  recurrence text NOT NULL DEFAULT 'none'::text,
  lat numeric NOT NULL,
  lon numeric NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_activity PRIMARY KEY (activity_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
      REFERENCES public.users (user_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

I want to calculate every day spare time for this user using PL/pgSQL function that takes `(user_id INTEGER, range_start TIMESTAMP, range_end TIMESTAMP)` as parameters. I want the output of this SQL statement:

```
SELECT * from calculate_spare_time(1, '2016-06-12', '2016-06-13');
```

to be like this:

```
spare_time_id | user_id   | starts_at                     | ends_at 

(serial)      | (integer) | (timestamp without time zone) |(timestamp without time zone)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1             | 1         | 2016-06-12 00:00:00           | 2016-06-12 08:00:00
2             | 1         | 2016-06-12 12:00:00           | 2016-06-12 16:00:00
3             | 1         | 2016-06-12 17:30:00           | 2016-06-12 18:00:00
4             | 1         | 2016-06-12 21:15:00           | 2016-06-13 00:00:00
5             | 1         | 2016-06-13 00:00:00           | 2016-06-13 10:00:00
6             | 1         | 2016-06-13 12:00:00           | 2016-06-13 18:00:00
7             | 1         | 2016-06-13 19:00:00           | 2016-06-14 00:00:00
```

I have the idea of subtracting the end time of one activity from the start time of the next activity happening on the same date, but I am stuck with implementing that with PL/pgSQL especially on how to deal with 2 rows in the same time.

Comment: Hope this edit makes my question clear.

Comment: Much better now. Are there any constraints on the data? Can time ranges of activities overlap? Can they be adjacent? Can columns be NULL? Are `starts_at` and `ends_at` *inclusive* or *exclusive* bounds? (Lower bound inclusive, upper bound exclusive, would be the canonical default.) Is there a 15-minute grid on allowed timestamps? The actual complete table definition (`CREATE TABLE` script with all constraints) would clarify all that. The function very much depends on what data must be expected.

Comment: I added the `CREATE TABLE` script to the post. Time ranges of activities can overlap only if activities take place in the same location which is represented by `lat` and `lon` columns. `starts_at` is an inclusive bound while  `ends_at` is an exclusive bound.

Comment: I don't understand what 15-minute grid on allowed timestamps is. I don't get the point of it.

Comment: "15-minute grid" would mean that time values are entered in 15 minute intervals, which would allow a discrete solution. I added a general solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify things, I suggest to create a view - or better yet: a [`MATERIALZED VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html) showing *gaps* in the activities per user:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_gap AS
SELECT user_id, tsrange(a, z) AS gap
FROM  (
   SELECT user_id, ends_at AS a
        , lead(starts_at) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY starts_at) AS z
   FROM   activity
   ) sub
WHERE  z > a;  -- weed out simple overlaps and the dangling "gap" till infinity
```

Note the [range type `tsrange`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html).

ATTENTION: You mentioned possible overlaps, which complicate things. If one time range of a single user can be *included* in another, you need to do more! Merge time ranges to identify earliest start and latest end per block.

Remember to refresh the MV when needed.

Then your function can simply be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_freetime(_user_id int, _from timestamp, _to timestamp)
  RETURNS TABLE (rn int, gap tsrange) AS
$func$
   SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY g.gap)::int AS rn
        , g.gap * tsrange(_from, _to) AS gap
   FROM   mv_gap g
   WHERE  g.user_id = _user_id
   AND    g.gap && tsrange(_from, _to)
   ORDER  BY g.gap;
$func$  LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_freetime(1, '2016-06-12 0:0', '2016-06-13 0:0');
```

Note the [range operators `*` and `&&`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html).
Also note that I use a simple SQL function, after the problem has been simplified enough. If you need to add more, you might want to switch back to plpgsql and use `RETURN QUERY` ...

Or just use the query without function wrapper.

#### Performance

If you have *many* rows per user, to optimize query times, add an SP-GiST index (one reason to use a MV):

```
CREATE INDEX activity_gap_spgist_idx on mv_gap USING spgist (gap);
```

In addition to an index on `(user_id)`.
Details in this related answer:

- [Perform this hours of operation query in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108477/native-way-of-performing-this-hours-of-operation-query-in-postgresql/22111524#22111524)

Comment: Thank you so much. It really helps me.