# How to compare current time to specified time of day and day of the week in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, time

I have a table of accounts and want to make it possible to specify allowed time for logging in for each of them, something like "9:00-19:00, mon-fri", so that later it was possible to check with one SELECT request.  Is it possible to?

Maybe I'm thinking in the wrong direction and it would be necessary to create columns like "start_time,end_time,start_day,end_day" but it seems redundant to me and I'm sure there is an easier way.

Comment: as there will be only a few such time restrictions make a new table put your 4 columns in it and reference it

Comment: we discourage using delimited columns see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: Go the `start_time,end_time,start_day,end_day` route.  This `9:00-19:00, mon-fri` is hard to validate and is mixing data types and requires effort to unpack to get at what you really want. Basically a recipe for problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick a model week and store actual time ranges for opening hours as [**`tsrange` (range of `timestamp without time zone`)**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) values. This way you can easily enforce valid data, and the check you are aiming for becomes **very** efficient with the right index(es). See:

- [Perform this hours of operation query in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108477/perform-this-hours-of-operation-query-in-postgresql/22111524#22111524)