# How to use uuid with postgresql gist index type?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, uuid, gist-index

I can't use directly uuid with gist index

```
CREATE INDEX idx_leaderboads_values_gist
  ON leaderboard_entry
  USING gist
  (id_leaderboard , value);
```

And I got this error:

> ERROR:  data type uuid has no default operator class for access method
>   "gist"
>
> HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a
>   default operator class for the data type.

Comment: yes I have my anwser

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Postgres 10 or newer

[btree_gist](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html) now also covers the data type `uuid`, like [Paul commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22720130/how-to-use-uuid-with-postgresql-gist-index-type/22720664?noredirect=1#comment80165715_22720664). (And some other data types, notably all `enum` types.)

Now all you need is to install the extension once per database:

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
```

Then your index should just work.

Related:

- [Exclusion constraint on a bitstring column with bitwise AND operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126180/exclusion-constraint-on-a-bitstring-column-with-bitwise-and-operator/11128280#11128280)
- [Creating multicolumn index in PostgreSQL, containing both scalar and array columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31945601/creating-multicolumn-index-in-postgresql-containing-both-scalar-and-array-colum/31946413#31946413)

#### Postgres 9.6 or older

(Original answer.)
Normally I would suggest the additional module [btree_gist](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html), but the type [`uuid`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html) is *not* covered by it.

In theory, since a UUID is `a 128-bit quantity` ([per documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html)), the most efficient way would be to convert it to two `bigint` or `float8` for the purpose of the index. But none of these casts are defined in standard Postgres.

I found a [stab in that direction in the pqsql-hackers list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAH3i69njJ9AX1fzHwt6uoUzCMBqnaDBwhmAPhRQzzLWifb2WOA@mail.gmail.com#CAH3i69njJ9AX1fzHwt6uoUzCMBqnaDBwhmAPhRQzzLWifb2WOA@mail.gmail.com), but it seems unsuccessful.

The remaining option is a functional GiST index on the `text` representation:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_leaderboads_values_gist
ON leaderboard_entry USING gist (id_leaderboard, cast("value" AS text));
```

To make use of this functional index, queries must match that expression. You can use the shorthand `"value"::text` in queries (but not in the index definition without adding more parentheses).

Aside: do not use `value` as column name it's a [reserved word in standard SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

The question is: **why** do you need the GiST index. The best solution depends on the objective.

Comment: I need to lookup value around one value in the leaderboard and I want to avoid to create two query to do it.

Comment: Now that Postgres 10 is out, `btree_gist` supports UUIDs, so you don't need to cast anymore.

Comment: @Paul: Great! Thanks for the update! I assume you are the author of the patch, too? Kudos!

Comment: Ha ha I originated it but several others got it over the finish line. :-)

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Postgres 10, and you migrated your database from a previous version using dump/restore, you may need to run:

```
ALTER EXTENSION btree_gist UPDATE;
```

in order to get gist indexes to work with UUID's.

Comment: Thanks! I think you just saved our deploy :D