# Creating multicolumn index in PostgreSQL, containing both scalar and array columns

Tags: arrays, postgresql, indexing

In order to optimize complex PostgreSQL query I've tried to create an index containing both scalar strings and arrays and supporting array operations (`@>`, `<@` and `&&`).

But I only managed to create a `BTREE` index so far:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx1
  ON "MyTable"
  USING btree
  ("Char_1", "Array_1", "Array_2", "Array_3", "Char_2");
```

which have no support for array operations (`@>`, `<@` and `&&`).

I've tried to use `GIN` and `GiST` (using `btree_gin` and `btree_gist` extensions), but I found no way to use both scalar and array columns in the same index.

It looks like `GIN` doesn't support scalars:

```
ERROR:  data type character has no default operator class for access method "gin"
HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.
```

while `GiST` does't support arrays:

```
ERROR:  data type character varying[] has no default operator class for access method "gist"
HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.
```

The only way I found to create such an index is by using `to_tsvector` function to convert all scalar strings to `tsvector` datatype. But I don't need full text search here. I even tried to create my own operator class, but quickly realized that it's beyond me.

Is there any way to create multicolumn `GIN`/`GiST` index, containing both scalar strings and arrays?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install the additional module [**`btree_gin`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gin.html) or [**`btree_gist`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html) respectively, which provide the missing operator classes.

Run once per database:

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gin;  -- or btree_gist
```

Then you should be able to create your multicolumn index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON "MyTable" USING gin
  ("Varchar_1", "Array_1", "Array_2", "Array_3", "Varchar_2");
```

See:

- [Multicolumn index on 3 fields with heterogenous data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658515/multicolumn-index-on-3-fields-with-heterogenous-data-types/22675324#22675324)

As for indexes on **array** types: **GIN** is the perfect index type for those. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html)

> GIN indexes are inverted indexes which can handle values that contain
> more than one key, **arrays for example**.

Bold emphasis mine.
The operators `@>`, `<@` and `&&` are defined for various data types. Some of them cooperate with GiST indexes as well. But with arrays as operands, it's typically GIN indexes. See:

- [Use PostgreSQL builtin operator <@ after including extension intarray](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/110650/3684)

The data type `character` is most probably **not** what you want. See:

- [Any downsides of using data type “text” for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20334221/939860)

Comment: Just as I said, `btree_gist` only adds support for ordinary data types. Try to create multicolumn gist index with an array field and you'll see exactly the same exception I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny: Ah, I see. No GiST index for array types. Why would you want that to begin with? Use a GIN index for those. Index usage is bound to the operators used: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29245753/939860. If that's still unclear I suggest you start a new question with the details of your use case.